# PriGrelha ShowDialog perde focus

Tags: c#

Ao utilizar a prigrelha num formulário de utilizador com ShowDialog o Primavera perde o focus. 
Testei com o código disponível aqui: 
https://github.com/PrimaverabssDeveloper/ERP10Extensibility/tree/master/Primavera%20SDK

Alterei o código do MainCustomCodeClass.cs:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e do frmDemoGrid.cs:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém já teve o mesmo problema? Estou a fazer alguma coisa mal?
Obrigado.

Comment: é o produto ou o componente que perde o focus?

Comment: é mesmo o produto. Quando o form faz o load, o focus muda para outra janela aberta no windows.

Comment: O que acontece aqui é que, quando é feito o ShowDialog o form fica fora da shell do ERP, no entanto, pelo teste que fiz, não está a perder o focus. Estás a invocar o form a partir de um menu de utilizador?

Comment: No exemplo que apresentei estou a invocar a partir de um atalho na ribbon. No caso real onde tenho o problema o form está a ser invocado a partir do Editor de Ordens de Fabrico.

Comment: O problema está mesmo onde o LoadGrid está colocado, experimenta passá-lo para o evento Shown do form, já não vai acontecer, a grelha será carregada imeditamente após o form ser mostrado.

Comment: de facto deixou de acontecer. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Favor não postar [código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/75104)

Answer (score 0):

De facto ficou ultrapassado passando o LoadGrid para o evento Shown.

```
private void frmDemoGrid_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadGrid();
        }
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.